# JQuery getting nth-level children

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

We all know that to get first level children selector is `div#block > div`
I am sure there is no css/jquery selector to get nth-level children. But if there is any workaround. Please help me. **I am not having any reference as id or class. The only reference is using tag names.**

```
<div id="block">
   <div>level 1
       <div>level 2</div>
       <div>level 2
           <div>level 3</div>
           <div>level 3</div>
       </div>
       <div>level 2
           <div>level 3
               <div>level 4</div>
           </div>
           <div>level 3</div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div>level 1
       <div>level 2
           <div>level 3
               <div>level 4</div>
           </div>
           <div>level 3</div>
       </div>
       <div>level 2</div>
   </div>
   <div>level 1
       <div>level 2</div>
       <div>level 2
           <div>level 3</div>
           <div>level 3</div>
       </div>
       <div>level 2
           <div>level 3</div>
           <div>level 3</div>
       </div>
       <div>level 2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming all are divs , If you know what n is , it should be easy right. You could use

```
$('div div div').children()
```

Comment: close but this will select all further levels as well.

Comment: i understand now. what do you want to do further?

Comment: you get your nth level object at this stage. So you can do whatever you desire. right?

Answer (score 7):

The workaround is to keep repeating `> div` until you get whichever level of children you want...

```
$('div#block > div > div') // level 2
$('div#block > div > div > div') // level 3
$('div#block > div > div > div > div') // level 4
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `> *`

Comment: That works too. Of course, it'll depend on what kind of elements we're looking for.